# How to install sqlcipher plugins in qt

Tags: sql, windows, qt, desktop, sqlcipher

I download the plugins from https://github.com/sjemens/qsqlcipher-qt5 to install sql plugins on my qt windows application. Whenever i build the code got this error in compile output

"mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/QT_Programs/sqlcipher/build-qsqlcipher-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/qsqlcipher'
cd C:/QT_Programs/sqlcipher/qsqlcipher-qt5/qsqlcipher/../3rdparty/libtomcrypt && make library CFLAGS=-fPIC
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:506: libtomcrypt] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/QT_Programs/sqlcipher/build-qsqlcipher-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/qsqlcipher'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:50: sub-qsqlcipher-make_first] Error 2
20:07:01: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qsqlcipher (kit: Desktop Qt 5.14.1 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make""

How to install make command in this qt project?